# ReactJS & Firebase - Ordering data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a React app querying Firebase with the following code:

```
const usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('totalSubs');

    usersRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let users = snapshot.val();

      let newState = [];

      for (let user in users) {
        newState.push({
          id: user,
          displayName: users[user].displayName,
          totalSubs: users[user].totalSubs,
          userImg: users[user].userImg
      });

      }
      this.setState({
        users: newState
      });
    });
```

My Firebase structure for 'users' can be seen here.

[image: database structure]

I have 3 different Google accounts that I'm testing with, which is why my name appears against each user.

I'd like to be able to display each user within my react app, in descending order of `totalSubs`, e.g. the user with the highest `totalSubs` at the top.

From other posts, I thought `.orderByChild('totalSubs');` would order the data and allow this, but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct, but you need to adjust the method you're using to extract data from the returned [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot).

From the [working with lists of data documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

> Attaching a `value` observer to a list of data will return the entire list of data as a single snapshot which you can then loop over to access individual children.
>
> Even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is still a list; it just contains a single item. To access the item, you need to loop over the result:
>
> ```
> ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
>   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
>     var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
>     var childData = childSnapshot.val();
>     // ...
>   });
> });
> ```

Therefore, with your example code, you'll need to make a couple of changes and iterate over the returned children using `forEach`:

```
const usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('totalSubs');

usersRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    let newState = [];

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        newState.push({
            id: childSnapshot.key,
            displayName: childSnapshot.val().displayName,
            totalSubs: childSnapshot.val().totalSubs,
            userImg: childSnapshot.val().userImg
        });
    });

    this.setState({
        users: newState
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. The only think I changed was during the output, which I reversed: {this.state.users.reverse().map((user) => {...

Thanks for taking the time to help!